# How to handle login errors properly with Vuex in Vue 2 app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm building a login page with Vue 2 and want to use Vuex to manage the state. I'm having issues properly handling login errors.

When the username/password is incorrect, it always goes into the loginView.vue .then() block and shows a successful login message.

My code:

#### api/auth.js

```js
import axios from "axios";

export default {
    login: function (credentials) {
        return axios.post(localhost + 'login', credentials)
        .then(({ data }) => data) 
        .catch(error => Promise.reject(error)); 
    }
}
```

#### store/auth.js

```js
import AuthApi  from '@/api/auth'
import axios from 'axios'

export const auth = {
    state: {
        user: null
    },
    getters: {
        // !! just converts the value to a boolean
        isLogged: state => !!state.user
    },
    mutations: {
        setUserData(state, userData) {
            state.user = userData
            localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(userData))
            axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${userData.token}`
        },

        clearUserData() {
            localStorage.removeItem('user')
            location.reload()
        }
    },
    actions: {
        login({ commit }, credentials) {
            AuthApi.login(credentials)
                .then(({ data }) => {
                    commit('setUserData', data)
                    return data; 
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                    throw error; 
                })
        },

        logout({ commit }) {
            commit('clearUserData')
        }
    },
}
```

#### LoginView.vue

```js
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            email: '',
            password: '',
        }
    },
    methods: {
        login() {
            this.$store.dispatch('login', {
                email: this.email,
                password: this.password
            })
                .then(() => {
                    alert('login success')
                    this.$router.push({ name: '/' })
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    alert(error.response.data.message)
                    console.log(error)
                })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

When the login fails on the backend, it returns:

[image]

I would appreciate it if experts could point out any mistakes and suggest modifications. Additionally, I'm looking for guidance on optimizing my code to ensure proper handling of exceptions and data transmission in the API -> store -> views flow. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You should always return a promise to chain. You don't do this in login